# Removing duplicates from lazy list Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, lazylist

I need to remove duplicates from lazy list. Here is some piece of code I managed to write but I have no clue on how to fix it to work properly.

I know how to do this using regular list, but lazy list are still new to me, so I will be happy with any help. Here is piece of code I tried to write:

```
let rec removeDuplicate = function
LNil -> LNil
|LCons(x,xf) -> x::(removeDuplicate (List.filter (fun a -> a<>x) xf));;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please, show us your type definition

Comment: type 'a llist = LNil

Comment: Maybe two posts in http://typeocaml.com/ would help u a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem, that I see in your code, is that instead of building lazy list in your second clause, you're actually building an OCaml's built-in `list`, with `::` consing operator. Also, you can't use `List.filter` on the tail part, since it also operates on values of type `'a list`, not yours list.

Comment: Ok, so I defined my own concatenating operator (@$) which actually does well with lazy list. Could you give me some hint on how to replace List.filter in this code?

Comment: A lazy list consists of a head and a function for calculating the tail. A filtered lazy list will have to look through the list (by calling the tail function if necessary) to get a good head. Then the filter function itself is the tail.

Comment: I can give you another hint, try to implement your own version of eager list, i.e., reimplement the ocaml's standard list, afterwards you will be able to solve your lazy list problem with ease. As a start ing hint, eager list type can be represented as `type 'a lst = Nil | Cons 'a * lst`.